# Matlab, system and exe

Tags: matlab

I want to execute exe in matlab.
code:

```
system('program1.exe')
```

it works , but how can I open two exe at a time.

```
system('program1.exe')
system('program2.exe')
```

will not work.

Answer (score 2):

Use the Windows `start` command to launch a program asynchronously.

```
system('start program1.exe')
system('start program2.exe')
```

There is a quirk with the syntax for `start`. If you quote the paths to the program exe, you *must* supply a quoted window title in front of it.

```
system('start "foo" "C:\path\to\program1.exe"')
system('start "bar" "C:\path\to\program2.exe"')
```

Type `help start` at the Windows Command Prompt to see doco for it.

You could also call the Java `java.lang.Runtime` class's `exec` method. All standard Java SE classes are available inside Matlab.

Answer (score 1):

You should either enter them in separate lines like this

```
system('program1.exe')
system('program2.exe')
```

or, if you want to keep them on a single line, insert a comma between them like this: `system('program1.exe'),system('program2.exe')`.

Comment: M. , i need to open both program at a time and not first program, close it and then open second one.

Comment: you can try entering system commands by prefixing with a `!`. For example, on unix, typing `!firefox` from within matlab will open firefox. Now if you want to open it in the background so that matlab doesn't wait for you to close the program, you can do `!firefox &` and you'll return to the prompt. The commands following `!` must be system commands and not Matlab functions. You can similarly issue multiple commands and Matlab will return to the prompt after executing the command. You'll have to try the equivalent commands in Windows/DOS.